# "NoReverseMatch" when in button that refers to a page with parameter in the url

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-templates, django-urls

I have this error:

"**NoReverseMatch at /home/2/
Reverse for 'calendar_new' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['home/(?P<group_id>\d+)/calendar/new/$']**"

in a button. In the ulr I have a "group_id" parameter which I need to use as a filter parameter. I don't understand what's wrong, because if I write the path manually in the url I don't have any problem and it opens the page correctly.
"group_id" is already a parameter present in the url.

In calendar.html:

```
<div class="cover-container d-flex w-100 h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
        <main class="inner cove border" role="main" style="background-color: white;">
            <h1 class="cover-heading mt-3">Lista Calendari di {{ nome }}</h1>
            
            <div class="mt-5">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    {% for calendar in object_list %}
                    <a href="{{ calendar.id }}"><li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">{{ calendar.name }}</li></a>
                    {% empty %}
                        <li class="list-group-item">Non ci sono calendari disponibili per questo edificio</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>
            
        </main>
    <!-- NUOVO CALENDARIO -->
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active mt-5 mb-5" href="{% url 'cal:calendar_new'%}">Aggiungi Calendario</a>
</div>
```

In urls.py:

```
url(r'^home/(?P<group_id>\d+)/$', views.CalendarsOfGroupView.as_view(), name='group_view'),
url(r'^home/(?P<group_id>\d+)/calendar/new/$', views.calendar, name='calendar_new'),
```

Comment: you should pass group_id parameter into url template tag
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#examples

Comment: Tahnks, I have read this documentation but have not been able to solve the problem. Now I write "href="{% url 'cal:calendar_new' calendar.group.id %}"" but it doesn't work

Comment: You haven't shown the view, so we don't know how to access `group_id` in the template. Remove the `{% url %}` tag for now, and try things like `{{ calendar.group.id }}` until you figure out how to show the group id in the template. I think `{{ view.kwargs.group_id }}` should work. You might find the the `{% debug %}` template tag or django debug toolbar helpful for issues like this.

Comment: calendar.group.id is not available there for sure as calendar is variable in for loop which is closed prior to this <a> tag, so calendar.group.id does not exist there hence same error

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! I solved it by writing as follows: "href="{% url 'cal:calendar_new' view.kwargs.group_id %}" "

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have group in context

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active mt-5 mb-5" href="{% url 'cal:calendar_new' group.id %}">Aggiungi Calendario</a>
```

As your url requires group_id parameter to be matched

Comment: Doesn't work! I 'm putting " href="{% url 'cal:calendar_new' calendar.group.id %}" " but even this doesn't work.